# Securing a raw sql query in Laravel to prevent injections

Tags: sql, laravel

The query when not trying any SQL injection fix works perfectly there is no any connection issue. It is only when trying to change the query to protect it from injections, when the syntax breaks.

I am trying to secure this raw query preventing sql injection

I have seen in the docs (and I know the prepared statements from goo'ol php)
and that Laravel shows a simple example such as this one:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
```

or this one

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

I am trying to do that where it corresponds, at the WHERE clause equaling the variable provided from the form $a, but all attempts break the syntax.

so anything like:

```
where author = ?, [$ba], or '$ba' or where author = :ba, ['author' => '$ba']
```

gives syntax errors.

```
    $ba = 'whatever';    
    $results = 
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT 
          t.id, t.AvgStyle, r.RateDesc
          FROM (
               SELECT
               p.id, ROUND(AVG(s.Value)) AS AvgStyle
               FROM posts p
               INNER JOIN styles s
               ON s.post_id = p.id  
               WHERE author = '$ba'    
               GROUP BY p.id
               ) t
               INNER JOIN rates r
                   ON r.digit = t.AvgStyle"
                        ));
```

Thank you.
Note> question is not eligible for bounties. It is someone always putting it on every question of mine without my permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was extremely close to what Everton said: It just needed to go one parentheses to the right.

That is:

```
, )[$ba]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
$ba = 'whatever';    
    $results = 
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT 
          t.id, t.AvgStyle, r.RateDesc
          FROM (
               SELECT
               p.id, ROUND(AVG(s.Value)) AS AvgStyle
               FROM posts p
               INNER JOIN styles s
               ON s.post_id = p.id  
               WHERE author = ?    
               GROUP BY p.id
               ) t
               INNER JOIN rates r
                   ON r.digit = t.AvgStyle"
          , )[$ba]); // @everton We just needed to move it one parentheses
```

The important thing here is that you need to respect the order if you have others parameters.

Comment: The error I get after trying that solution is>
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: SELECT 
QueryException in Connection.php line 713:

Comment: Which database are you using? Mysql? How are you executing this query?

Comment: yes, mysql but the query without the sql injection fix works perfect. The change in the syntax to fix it is what makes the query not run. I have got lots of queries running so the issue is that the fix for the raw sql is not fitting as sql expects it, smth must be in.

Comment: Have you tried calling ->get() at the end of this query? I'll update my answer.

Comment: Look the answer I posted. You were extremely close as I suspected, just needed to go one place to the right of the last but one parentheses.
Obrigado